# Why is "less" much slower than "grep"?

Tags: unix

I sometimes have to look through files that are several gigs and have noticed that finding what I am looking for with grep is much faster than with less. Why could that be? I am talking about looking for a certain tag/word, not even any complicated regex.

Comment: Not an answer, but have you considered using grep and then a pipe to pass the results onto less?

Comment: Yes, I usually use grep with -A/B/C to get some context around what I am searching for but sometimes I need more flexibility as I am looking at log files and need to be able to scroll around and incrementally search from there on/before

Comment: You can use https://github.com/tigrawap/slit as a much faster `less` replacement.

Answer (score 10):

By default, 'less' calculates line numbers, which can slow it down. Try using the '-n' option to suppress line number calculations and see if that speeds things up.

Comment: I think the line counting happens once grep has found your match - then you see "Calculating line numbers" and it takes a while before it lets you do anything, but you can cancel that with ctrl+c. It doesn't look like the -n helps with the actual search speed.

Comment: That did the trick for me. Noticed a huge difference (as in tens of seconds vs instantaneous response) when opening a nearly 10GB log file and hitting shift G to get to the end of the file.

Comment: @MarcelloRomani shift-G has nothing to do with search though

Comment: Two additional tips: (1) "50%" or "55%" can move instantly through the file and if there is a timestamp prefix or pattern, you can jump forward to the relevant section before searching. (2) `grep -20000 PATTERN file | less` shows 20k lines of context before and after all pattern-matches so if you now search with less, it will be fast